# What to do if you want the Active Directory MMC plugin to be available?

Tags: windows, active-directory, mmc

I don't understand or think that much about active directory. Right now I am just wondering how the following icon comes up on my desktop. What needs to be installed on my machine to get it.

[image]

More info: That particular icon calls `dsa.msc` which resides in the **system32** windows directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the Active Directory MMC Plugin (dsa.msc) you'll need the following:

Windows XP SP1 and later or Windows Server 2003:
[adminpak.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16770)

Windows Vista: [RSAT Tools for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21090)

Windows 7:
[RSAT Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887)

Windows 10: [RSAT Tools for Windows 10 v1.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) from Microsoft.  Installation is wonky.  You download and install the software, THEN, go into Add Remove Programs, Turn Windows Features On/Off and check the tools you want enabled on your PC.

Comment: RSAT is only for Win7 computers.

Comment: And Vista.  The OP didn't mention the OS so the answer is correct

Comment: Why the vote-down?  These steps are required to actually use the tools.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the OS you are using.  But it looks like XP.  You'll want to download the Administration Tools Pack from Microsoft.